# How to assign a filtered list to another list

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, project

I need to assign a filtered list to another list, however I do not know the list structure that will filter, just know the parameter for the filter. It Only returns an SPListItemCollection  and I need to return a SPList.

Below follows method in which capture the list, I need to return a list, but filtered by query:

```
/// <summary>
        /// reads the list to display
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SPList GetListFromProjectWorkSpace()
        {
            SPList list = null;

            Guid projUID = _helper.GetProjUID();
            if (projUID == Guid.Empty)
            {
                return list;
            }

            // read project data
            IProjectWssInfoDataSet dataset = _service.ReadWssData(projUID);
            if (dataset.ProjWssInfo.Count == 0)
            {
                return list;
            }

            // get workspace name and url
            string workspaceName = dataset.ProjWssInfo[0].WorkspaceName;
            string workspaceUrl = dataset.ProjWssInfo[0].WorkspaceUrl;


            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(()=>
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(workspaceUrl))
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < site.AllWebs.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (!site.AllWebs[i].ServerRelativeUrl.Contains(workspaceName))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                list = site.AllWebs[i].Lists[SelectedList];

                            }
                            catch
                            {
                            }


                        }

                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                        query.Query = @"<Where>
                                          <Contains>
                                             <FieldRef Name='LinkFilenameNoMenu' />
                                             <Value Type='Computed'>work</Value>
                                          </Contains>
                                       </Where>";



                        SPListItemCollection  itens = list.Items.List.GetItems(query);

                // I need help here




                }
            });


            return list;
        }
```

att,

Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to “assign a list into another list”. You have to understand the fundamental distinction between list *metadata* and list *content* (items):

- `SPList` represents the *metadata* of a list;
- `SPListItemCollection` contains particular *items* of a list — its *data*.

In case you need to copy the (filtered) content of one list into another list, you have to understand the structures (permitted content types, fields) of both lists and copy the items one by one (with possible data transformations).

Note: to get the list's metadata knowing a collection of its items, there the `SPListItemCollection.List` property.

Comment: But how can I find these structures? In my case, I caught a parameter that is the name of the list and from that list that do the logic, but I do not know the structure of this list and its content type.


You can show a block of code that do this?


Thank you

Comment: Have a look at some basic documentation like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460897.aspx. Or edit your question and provide your code you've created so far.